# Nested ( master detail ) table in html

Tags: html, css

I added child table in tr but I am unable to make a grid like shown in mockup.

[image]

Basically, I got the idea from dev extreme grid. https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/MasterDetailView/Angular/Light/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use further `<tr>`, `<td>`, `<th>` elements to do what you need, since it seems like you want to keep the same table layout for the pseudo-child-tables:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Teader Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>address</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>32 block</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Student Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>DEF</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>GHI</td>
      <td>32 block</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Student Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>JKL</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>MNO</td>
      <td>32 block</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Student Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>PQR</td>
      <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```